# Sublime 3 - Highlight variable in Perl/PHP string

Tags: sublimetext3

I am turning to use Sublime3 instead of Notepad++. I have some concern when working with Perl/PHP or any kind of languages that use dollar sign for declare variable.

Here is an example, in Notepad ++:

[image]

As can be seen, "HELO $name" was displayed with different colors.

By that way, we can easily recognize there is a variable in the string.

In Sublime 3 , it looked like this:

[image]

So you can see there are no different between text and variable. It would caused confusion in some case.

May I know is there are any solution for this ?

Thank you and best regards.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*This is self-promoting, but it will actually solve the problem*</sup>

You may want to check out my [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), available via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). Its goal is to make as many languages as possible look as good as possible, and has hundreds of selectors that are specific for many different syntaxes, including Perl and PHP. Specifically, both languages support highlighting for string interpolation. Here is your code using Sublime's Perl syntax from [dev build](https://sublimetext.com/3dev) 3118, which should be very similar to the latest [public build](https://sublimetext.com/3), which you should be using if you're not registered yet:

[image: Perl]

And here is the equivalent code in PHP:

[image: PHP]

Please note that these images were taken using a work-in-progress version of Neon, which I'm planning on releasing in the next day or so. The current version should look the same, as I don't think I've edited any of these scopes, but if not just let me know and I'll point you to the dev version.